# Canvas: Convert Images into grayscale

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgW = imgObj.width;
var imgH = imgObj.height;
canvas.width = imgW;
canvas.height = imgH;
canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);
for(>var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
 for(>var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
      var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
      var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
      imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
      imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
      imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
 }
}

canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
return canvas.toDataURL();
```

codes above are the standard implementation. 
here is a specific code: `var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;`
I know that we should grasp each pixel and get the average, but I know why would it use `(y * 4)* imgPixel.width + x * 4`

I am a freshman from China, hope I can get a help from all of you. If you can help me, I would really appreciate it. thanks!

Comment: Refer this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-grayscale-image-colors-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The image is represented by a single-dimensional array of values. Each pixel in the image consumes 4 consecutive entries in the array. The four values represent the red, blue, green, and alpha (transparency) channels of an image pixel.

That expression converts the `(x, y)` conceptual location of a pixel into the point in the linear array where the four values corresponding to that location can be found. The `y` coordinate gives the row of the pixel, so `y` is multiplied by the image width — each row of the image consumes that many pixels. The `x` coordinate is the offset into that row.  Each of the values `y` and `x` must be multiplied by `4` to account for the four-entry representation of each pixel.